# pushState() dismissing 'remember password' dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, pushstate

I suppose I have an interesting problem, and after several days of thinking and research, I have been unable to come up with a solution.

I am coding a web-application inspired by phpMyAdmin, and it thus uses frames to control content placement.  Due to this, any url visited will always be index.php.. unless I use the history API's `pushState()` method to alter the url to reflect the page being visited in the frame.

The problem however, comes from this method; upon login, the user is redirected from `login.html` to `index.php`, and for a split second, chrome asks if it wants me to remember the password..  that little bar then disappears as the visit triggers the `pushState()` method.  This behavior is not something I want the application to continue to commit.  I want the user to be able to store their password should they wish it(I haven't gotten into cookies yet, I'm still rather new at this).

I've tried thinking of checks I could place revolving around the last page visited, but that hasn't panned out due to my experience regarding such..  so more eyes on this would be appreciated for any ideas on how to solve the problem.

If it helps at all, my current code for triggering this is..

```
$(window).on('load', function (){
    window.parent.history.pushState(null, "index.php", "index.php");
});
```

So far this behavior only occurs on Chrome.  Firefox and IE behave as expected.

Comment: The title says that `pushState()` is refreshing the page but from the description it seems that it is not. Instead the issue is that `pushState()` dismisses the remember password dialog. Can you clarify?

Comment: @SeanHogan I've edited the title and clarified slightly regarding other browsers.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you need the initial `pushState()`?

Comment: @SeanHogan Initially, I don't need it, but I haven't figured out a way to develop a check for that.  I would need it in every other case aside from the initial login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid the initial pushstate

```
(function($) {
  var firstLoad=true;
  $(window).on('load', function (){
    if (firstLoad!==true)
      window.parent.history.pushState(null, "index.php", "index.php");
    firstLoad=false;
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It turns out that this didn't work for reasons already described above, but with a little modification - the variable placed on the parent of the frame, and accessed through `window.parent.variable` - I was able to get the script behaving as it should, so I'm going to accept this as the answer that solved the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(function($) { 
    var isFirst = true;


    $(window).on('load', function (evt){

        if(isFirst && wasLastPage('index.html')) return;
        isFirst = false;

        window.parent.history.pushState(null, "index.php", "index.php");

    });

    function wasLastPage(pageName){
        //document.referrer only works in non IE
        var lastPage = (document.referrer)? document.referrer : '';

        return (lastPage.indexOf(pageName) === lastPage.length - pageName.length);
    }

});
```

Comment: I just edited, i didn't realize it was optional for you to ignore the first push state. Per Deadalus commmet.

Comment: I actually already tried using referrer, and it won't work as the index page will always be the referrer.